# Bitbucket pipeline Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address

Tags: git, bitbucket-pipelines

I am trying to integrate into my bitbucket pipeline an automated tag creation
So basically I have a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# retrieve branch name
BRANCH_NAME=$(git branch | sed -n '/\* /s///p')

# remove prefix release
REGEXP_RELEASE="release\/"
VERSION_BRANCH=$(echo "$BRANCH_NAME" | sed "s/$REGEXP_RELEASE//") 

echo "Current version branch is $VERSION_BRANCH"

# retrieve the last commit on the branch
VERSION=$(git describe --tags --match=$VERSION_BRANCH* --abbrev=0)

# split into array
VERSION_BITS=(${VERSION//./ })

#get number parts and increase last one by 1
VNUM1=${VERSION_BITS[0]}
VNUM2=${VERSION_BITS[1]}
VNUM3=${VERSION_BITS[2]}
VNUM3=$((VNUM3+1))

#create new tag
NEW_TAG="$VNUM1.$VNUM2.$VNUM3"

echo "Updating $VERSION to $NEW_TAG"

#get current hash and see if it already has a tag
GIT_COMMIT=`git rev-parse HEAD`
NEEDS_TAG=`git describe --contains $GIT_COMMIT`

#only tag if no tag already (would be better if the git describe command above could have a silent option)
if [ -z "$NEEDS_TAG" ]; then
    echo "Tagged with $NEW_TAG (Ignoring fatal:cannot describe - this means commit is untagged) "
    git tag $NEW_TAG
    git push --tags
else
    echo "Already a tag on this commit"
fi
```

Then my pipeline:

```
# This is a sample build configuration for Java (Maven).
# Check our guides at https://confluence.atlassian.com/x/zd-5Mw for more examples.
# Only use spaces to indent your .yml configuration.
# -----
# You can specify a custom docker image from Docker Hub as your build environment.
image: maven:3.3.9

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        caches:
          - maven
        script: # Modify the commands below to build your repository.
          - mvn clean package -Denv=uat
  branches:
    master:
      - step:
          caches:
            - maven
          script: # Modify the commands below to build your repository.
            - mvn clean package -Denv=uat
            - chmod +x tag.sh
            - ./tag.sh
```

However when pipeline tries to push the tag I am getting error:

```
./tag.sh<1s
+ ./tag.sh
Current version branch is master
Updating master-1.0.2 to master-1.0.3fatal: cannot describe '493bf0b1aef120879af57e25d63dde24ad0c7de2'
Tagged with master-1.0.3 (Ignoring fatal:cannot describe - this means commit is untagged)

Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '104.192.143.3' to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.Please make sure you have the correct access rightsand the repository exists.
```

So what I don' t understand is why I am getting this issue and how to solve it.
I read https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/use-ssh-keys-in-bitbucket-pipelines-847452940.html
But I did not understand as first I do not have access to the pipeline remote. And as the IP change I cannot add it as Known host.
Is there a way to do a push to the repo on which I am performing the build?

As the tags have been found and the repo has been cloned it means that I can certainly do a push.

Comment: So you are saying SSH keys are already added but the known hosts file is not updated, which is causing this error?

Comment: To be honnest I dont know. I just saw in the log that repo is cloned. the build need the repo  :) and i am able to run other commands except the push

Comment: And you are pushing to bitbucket only?

Comment: I want to push on the repo on which I am making the build. A simple push tag

Answer (score 0):

The REPO does not contain a reference to your public SSH key or the Docker image that the pipeline is running contains an SSH key that the repo doesn't know about in it's authorized_keys file.

Make sure:
- SSH Key on Docker Bitbucket pipeline image is present and correct
- Check which keys are authorized to access the bitbucket repository to ensure that the right public key is granted access.

That error is usually an issue with SSH key mismatch. I've run into it multiple times.

Other things to check for:
- If you configured the public key make sure you used CAT command (if running on nix) as copy/paste from editors is not reliable. 
- If you copy/pasted from somewhere else check to make sure the public key on